# How to boot my Raspberry Pi into the GUI without raspi-config?

Tags: raspbian, gui, raspi-config

I'm using a custom wheezy binary by OLA (Open Lighting Architecture): https://www.openlighting.org/ola/tutorials/ola-on-raspberry-pi/

I tried enabling the boot into Desktop via `sudo raspi-config` - but when I reboot, it stays in Command Line.

I took a look at `/boot/config.txt` - but there are no options for GUI booting.

How can I boot into GUI?

Comment: Do you know if there's even a GUI installed on OLA's version?  Usually they are enabled by default if they are.

Comment: You're right - there was no GUI installed on this build!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `startx` in `~/.bash_profile`. There are other ways of doing it but that's nice and simple. You may have to install it first if it's not included in your custom distribution of choice. (test if `startx` works from the command line first)

Answer (score 2):

Run `systemctl set-default graphical.target`, assuming an up-to-date system with graphical packages installed.

On Wheezy, the equivalent was setting default rulevel to 5 in `/etc/inittab`:

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

Running `startx` from `.bash_profile` is wasteful (it will start every time you open a terminal, crash, and then you'll get to the command prompt), and system applets (network manager, volume control, etc.) may not be working correctly.